# How do you evaluate the prediction accuracy of linear mixed models?

Tags: mixed-model, panel-data, prediction, validation

How does one evaluate prediction accuracy with uncertainty for linear mixed models?  Let's say I do bootstrapping and do train/test each time, and want to generate confidence intervals for some accuracy number like MAE.  Clearly the within-subjects observations are not independent, so I can't just take the MAE of *all* observations.  I could take the MAE within each subject, and average them.  Then generate confidence intervals for the mean of within-subjects MAEs.  This seems valid, but is there something better to do?

Any references/book sections to read would also be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using linear mixed models for prediction, rather than just penalised regression?

Comment: Because I have longitudinal data and I want to take into account individual differences that aren't explained by covariates.